# How to satisfy or bypass viewstate validation in Asp.net WebForms on separate post?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, webforms, viewstate

I`ve got a link in a Webforms page which opens in a new window, and posts to a form other than the page itself. This is done like this:

**JS:**

```
var submitFunc = function(){
    document.forms[0].action = 'http://urlToPostTo/somePage.aspx';  
    document.forms[0].target = '_blank'; 
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

**The link:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="myDataId" value="12345" />     
<a href="javascript:submitFunc();">Search</a>
```

As you can see, this overrides the target of the main `<form>`, and attempts to post to a different page. The whole point is that this should post/submit to a different page, while avoiding passing the data of "myDataId" as a *Get* parameter.

The above code would work, but causes an error due to viewstate validation.

**Question**: Is there any way for me to either satisfy the requirements here, or somehow bypass the viewstate validation so I can post my data this way?

Comment: What you're trying to do is [Cross-Page Posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to change the **`PostBackUrl`** of the button that submits the form.

A simple example **PostToPage1.aspx** that posts to **PostToPage2.aspx** (instead of a postback):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="text2" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/PostToPage2.aspx" />
</div>
</form>
```

You can then inspect the `Request` in `PostToPage2.aspx` to check if it's a POST, etc. and then access the `Request.Form` collection in the `Request` in `Page_Load`.

An overly simplified sample for **PostToPage2.aspx** (do add proper validation):

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack && Request.RequestType == "POST")
    {
        if (Request.Form != null && Request.Form.Keys.Count > 0)
        {
           .....
```

Hth...

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this gives an error saying I can only use one single Server-side `form` tag. I'm trying out some variations of this now.

Comment: @Kjartan yes, the above **isn't** adding yet another server side form. It is using the _same server side form_ that all ASP.net Web Forms pages use.

Comment: Yup, I finally realized that, and managed to get it working. Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: how do I get value of `text1` in PostToPage2.aspx?

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding there already is a sample above that inspects the HTTP POSTed values. At the end of the day, it's the  `name` form field (rendered by Asp.net) of whatever input type control in the "origin" page - just like any other vanilla html form that POSTs data somewhere...

Comment: @EdSF I see, that `name` rendered by asp.net is really ugly though, not `text1` or `text2` but something like `ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$text1`, crazy!.

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding Yes, that's how it gets rendered. You can try [`static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) mode and see if it helps. You can also try ["html server controls" instead of asp.net controls](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7860706/304683) and see if that makes it simpler. If you don't need to manipulate server side, then just use a standard `<input name="foo"...` (not a server side control of any kind).  Hth.