# C#/asp.net geting error when sending data from one page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send data from one page to another in C# ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768674/send-data-from-one-page-to-another-in-c-sharp-asp-net)

Hi I am trying to send data from one page to another in asp.net I found various methods of doing so and am gona try a few to se how they work but I seem to be getting an error on my first attempt.Here is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go" 
    PostBackUrl="~/Default2.aspx" />
<br />
```

I am sending the data from Default.aspx to Default2.aspx.
At the Default2.aspx in the Page_Load method I wrote this to retrieve the data:

```
  if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        string txtBox1 = ((TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
    }
```

From what I read on MSDN this should work but I must be missing something because when I pres the button to send the data and Default2.aspx loads I get an error page that looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using Server.Transfer?

Comment: NO this is the entire code I used for this.I used PostBackUrl="~/Default2.aspx" to send data to Default2.aspx

Comment: Then what you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you please post an answer with how I shoudl have written the code for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use master page for Default.aspx then Page.PreviousPage.FindControl doesn't work. Because when using masterpage, all controls in Default.aspx are placed in ContentPlaceHolder not directy in Form. So you can use below code:

```
Page.PreviousPage.Form.FindControl("yourContentPlaceHolderID").FindControl("TextBox1");
```

i assume you use masterpage. Otherwise your first code must work. In addition if you dont use masterpage and textbox is placed in PlaceHolder or Panel, your code won't work as well. FindControl doesnt recursively search in child container controls.

See the link. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx)

Comment: Yes I am using masterpages thank you for the info

Answer (score 1):

`Page.PreviousPage` is only available when using `Server.Transfer` to redirect to a new page. If this is a standard `GET` or `POST`, or `Response.Redirect` then this code will not work.

From your previous page. Use `Server.Transfer` to be able to access the previous page data.

Comment: If I understand this corectly Server.Trasfer transfer the data to the second page.Right?If that is so isen't that what PostBackUrl="~/Default2.aspx" also does?

Comment: `Server.Transfer` loads a new page in the same request (remembers old page).`Response.Redirect` loads a new page in a new request (forgets old page). The [`PostBackUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) on the button simply defines what page to post to.

Comment: I think what you want is just `((TextBox)this.FindControl("TextBox1)).Text;` or `this.TextBox1.Text;`