# Why to use ASP tags instead of HTML tags?

Tags: html, asp.net

I had started to learn ASP.NET, and i find that ASP has a lot of itself "view" tags that rendered in compilation time to HTML tags.

For example:

- `<asp:Lable>`
- `<asp:Literal>`
- `<asp:PlaceHolder>`

I understand the differences between each of them, but i do not understand why to use them and not simply to use the HTML tags? what are their benefits on the HTML tags?

Thanks

Comment: The main purpose to use asp control is that, It is easy to use in backend code. All this controls use for different-different functionality like Place holder combine the multiple control into single control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859923/asp-control-vs-html-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not just "tags", they represent *controls* that you can access from codebehind.

For instance a placeholder can be used to inject extra controls (or HTML code) based on "some condition".

More information can be found [here](https://www.asp.net/web-forms)

Answer (score -1):

That tag is asp.net control it is work on server side and using that control we access the value of control in server side.

HTML tag is only display HTML design in browser it is use for only display purpose.

Comment: You use the runat="server" to access an element even if it's a regular HTML tag.